# Javascript not calling my PHP the way I expect it

Tags: javascript, php

Can't seem to know what am I missing here. Javascript returns 0. Here are my files

**index.html**

```
<html>

<head>
<title> New </title>
<script src="alpha.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="desc" placeholder="Description"><br>
<button onclick="addParticular()">Submit</button>

<p id="demo"> Response goes Here </p>
</body>
</html>
```

**alpha.js**

```
function addParticular()
{
    var desc = document.getElementById("desc").value;

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "new.php?q='" + desc + "'", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**new.php**

```
<?php
include_once("conn.php");

$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
echo $q + " Hello World!";
?>
```

> Why is the response 0, and not [What's written in the textbox] + Hello World?
>
> How do I see the opened URL by XMLHttp?
>
> Should I really use $_REQUEST instead of $_GET?

Comment: echo $q + " Hello World!"; That's incorrect syntax for php. Otherwise, it works fine on my side :)

Comment: _Never_ use `$_REQUEST` if you want to be secure. It is a combination of `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE`, but you have no clue as to the real source.

Comment: @DovBenyominSohacheski that is misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to concatenate in PHP using a dot:

```
<?php
    include_once("conn.php");
    $q = $_REQUEST["q"];
    echo $q . " Hello World!"; // Instead of `echo $q + " Hello World!";`
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you concatenate with the `.` operator. You have:

```
echo $q + " Hello World!";
```

This will attempt to *add* the two as numbers. You’re lucky to get 0.

You should use:

```
echo $q . " Hello World!";
```

More simply, you can use:

```
echo "$q Hello World!";
```

which is marginally more efficient, and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Error in this line-

```
echo $q + " Hello World!";
```

It should be -

```
echo $q . " Hello World!";
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick quote from the [documentation of PHP strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.useful-funcs):

> Strings may be concatenated using the '.' (dot) operator. Note that the '+' (addition) operator will not work for this.

The expression `$q + " Hello World!"` is evaluated in numeric context. The strings are converted to numbers then added. The conversion of strings to numbers is explained in the same [documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion):

> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero).

That should explain why the result you get is `0` (zero) and also how to fix it.